# How to inject posts from certain category on home page

Tags: loop

I would like to make special first page of the blog (only the first landing page).
It will look like this :
2 newest posts from category A
2 newest posts from category B
2 newest posts from category C
Rest of posts from all categories (excluding those 6 posts above)

and on the next page will be continuing all new posts from all categories.

Is there a way to make it via loop ?

Thank you